# How to fix this `group_by` statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm am having an issue with a simple `dplyr`, `group_by` and `summarise` chain.

I have a tibble with 542 procedures performed for different diagnoses.
Here are two selected columns:

```
> data %>% select(Diagnosis, Split)
# A tibble: 542 x 2
   Diagnosis Split
       <dbl> <dbl>
 1         5     4
 2         3     3
 3         1     1
 4         1     1
 5         3     3
 6         1     1
 7         1     1
 8         2     2
 9         7     4
10         1     1
# … with 532 more rows
```

I want to summarise the data to see how many procedures were performed per
diagnosis:

```
> data %>% group_by(Diagnosis) %>% summarise(procedures =n())
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Diagnosis procedures
      <dbl>      <int>
1         1        262
2         2         91
3         3         63
4         4         36
5         5         37
6         6         31
7         7         22
```

But now I'd rather know the diagnosis names as the numbers are meaningless so I
create a 'look-up table' of sorts:

```
>diagNames    <- c("1" = "ENT",
+                  "2" = "MND",
+                  "3" = "CVA",
+                  "4" = "INJ",
+                  "5" = "NEU",
+                  "6" = "UNK",
+                  "7" = "OES"
)
```

Then I re-write the grouped summary like this:

```
> data %>%
+      group_by (diagnosis = diagNames[Diagnosis]) %>%
+      summarise(procedures = n())
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  diagnosis procedures
  <chr>          <int>
1 CVA               63
2 ENT              262
3 INJ               36
4 MND               91
5 NEU               37
6 OES               22
7 UNK               31
```

While the order of the output has changed to the alphabetical order of the
diagnosis column, the actual output is exactly what I want and I could
`arrange()` it if I wanted.

Now I have a second tibble for a different set of 427 procedures, this time I
want a summary grouped by gender:

```
> data %>% select(Sex, Success)
# A tibble: 427 x 2
     Sex Success
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     0       1
 2     1       1
 3     0       1
 4     0       1
 5     0       1
 6     0       1
 7     1       0
 8     1       1
 9     1       1
10     1       1
# … with 417 more rows

> data %>%
      group_by (Sex) %>%
      summarise(procedures = n())
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    Sex procedures
  <dbl>      <int>
1     0        157
2     1        270
```

Again, I'd rather the gender was readable text than a forgettable number. So, a
look-up table:

```
> genderNames <- c("0" = "Woman",
+                  "1" = "Man"
+ )
```

I then re-write the grouped summary, using pretty much the same syntax as I did
on the first tibble:

```
> data %>%
+     group_by (gender = genderNames[Sex]) %>%
+     summarise(procedures = n())
Error: Column `gender` must be length 427 (the number of rows) or one, not 270
```

Why is this generating an error when the first example didn't?

I've tried to troubleshoot; the only difference I can see is that 'Diagnosis'
was from 1-7 whereas 'Sex' starts with 0. Surely this isn't the problem?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to  convert the 'Sex' to `character` and then do the `genderName[Sex]`

Comment: Another workflow that is more intuitive for me would be performing the summary and then joining on a dimension data.frame mapping # to label. That said I'm pretty sure @akrun is correct in their assessment of mismatching types.

Comment: akrun nailed it. `Sex` is numeric, and `Diagnosis` is numeric. When you index your look-up with a numeric vector, the names are ignored, you are using index numbers. You can do `genderName[as.character(Sex)]`, but using a lookup data frame and joining might be cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned previously by the OP, the use of a 0 index is breaking the code.

This solution uses two packages from the tidyverse. You will need to load the following:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
```

One way to fix this would be to simply wrap the Sex variable in as.character().

```r
data %>%
  group_by(gender = genderNames[as.character(Sex)]) %>%
  summarise(procedures = n())
```

An alternative would be to create a tibble to use as a lookup table and join on that table.

```r
genderLookup <- tibble(Sex = c(0,1), gender = c('Woman','Man'))
```

Then you can join on the newly created lookup table.

```r
data %>%
  left_join(genderLookup, keep = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise(procedures = n())
```

keep = FALSE will drop the joining variable.

Either way works, but the second is more favorable for readability and debugging.

Comment: Thanks, great answer & explanation. Haven’t got as far as `left_join()` in my learning about `dplyr` but I’ll look it up & explore now. (Btw, love the profile name)